# Json to PHP - How to take a specific value from an array nested in a bigger array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to use the TheMovieDatabase API to take some information to put on my script.
I've correctly decoded the output using

```
$data['moviecrew'] = json_decode($movie_crew);
```

Now, the $data['moviecrew'] array is the following:

> "crew":[{"credit_id":"52fe43409251416c750094c5","department":"Directing","id":59026,"job":"Director","name":"Peyton
>   Reed","profile_path":"/h9lEnyQ60EjKRT3ZAOcrqQVlwn3.jpg"},{"credit_id":"52fe43409251416c750094f3","department":"Writing","id":52934,"job":"Screenplay","name":"Nicholas
>   Stoller","profile_path":"/qwcx9bdVhmyjWb0KOCdRHDXoFZ9.jpg"},{"credit_id":"52fe43409251416c750094f9","department":"Writing","id":62763,"job":"Screenplay","name":"Jarrad
>   Paul","profile_path":"/qWaXQi5Pz6jEKw9E2xRuX74phiB.jpg"}, ..

What I would like to do is to take the "Director" name to put in my PHP script.
I tried the following code:

```
<?php if($moviecrew->crew->job == "Director"){echo $moviecrew->crew->name;} ?>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and it gives me the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: film/filmsheet.php
>   Line Number: 36
>   Backtrace:
>   File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain.com/application/views/film/filmsheet.php
>   Line: 36
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain.com/application/controllers/Film.php
>   Line: 106
>   Function: view
>   File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain.com/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

The line 36 is just:

```
<?php if($moviecrew->crew->job == "Director"){echo $moviecrew->crew->name;} ?>
```

How could I solve this issue? Thanks for your kind support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things there one of which may be a copy/paste error from your code sample.

At first you have `$data['moviecrew']` then you try and use the variable `$moviecrew` which is not present in your question. (Is it present in the code?)

Assuming you have done `$moviecrew = $data['moviecrew']`, you will run into the following problem:

"crew" is an array not an object, so you'd need to loop over them all.

```
foreach ($moviecrew->crew as $crewMember) {
    if ($crewMember->job === 'Director') {
        echo $crewMember->name;
    }
}
```

But you want to extract just the director's name, so if we assume there is always only ever one director:-

```
$director = null;

foreach ($moviecrew->crew as $crewMember) {
    if ($crewMember->job === 'Director') {
        $director = $crewMember->name;
        break;
    }
}

if (!is_null($director)) {
    echo $director;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works like a charm! Thanks bcmcfc :) About your highlight, I'm using Codeigniter framework. The $data['moviecrew'] has been declared in a Controller. After declaration of the $data object, I can assign it to a specific page usign the form $this->load->view('film/filmsheet', $data). In this way I can use the $data['moviecrew'] object like $moviecrew.